# "error: unreported exception EmptyFileException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" in java when compiling my driver

Tags: java

First time posting here, if the format is awry I'll try to fix it. Anyway so I keep getting this error in java when trying to run my driver. The goal of the program is to write and then read from a file, I wrote to the file just fine and now I'm trying to read from it and here is the error:

unreported exception EmptyFileException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

University ufl = University.readFromFile("university.txt");

```
//read from file
public static University readFromFile(String filename) throws EmptyFileException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    University university = null;
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(file);
        String str = in.nextLine();
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(":");
        in2.next(); 
        String uName = in2.next();

        //Read University info
        str = in.nextLine();
        in2 = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(":");
        in2.next(); 
        String uTerm = in2.next();
        str = in.nextLine();
        in2 = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(":");
        in2.next(); 
        int uYear = in2.nextInt();
        str = in.nextLine();
        in2 = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(":");
        in2.next(); 
        int uNumStudents = in2.nextInt();
        str = in.nextLine();
        in2 = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(":");
        in2.next(); 
        int uNumInstructors = in2.nextInt();
        str = in.nextLine();
        in2 = new Scanner(str).useDelimiter(":");
        in2.next(); 
        int uNumCourses = in2.nextInt();

        //Create and read arrays of objects
        Student[] uStudents = new Student[uNumStudents];
        for(int i = 0; i < uNumStudents; i++)
                        uStudents[i] = readStudent(in);

        Instructor[] uInstructors = new Instructor[uNumInstructors];
        for(int i = 0; i < uNumInstructors; i++)
                        uInstructors[i] = readInstructor(in);

                    //Create array of possible TAs to pass into readCourse method
                    GradStudent[] gStudents = new GradStudent[uNumStudents];
                    for(int j=0; j<uStudents.length; j++) {
                        for(int i=0; i<uStudents.length; i++) {
                            if(uStudents[i] instanceof GradStudent)
                                gStudents[j] = (GradStudent) uStudents[i];
                        }
                    } 

        Course[] uCourses = new Course[uNumCourses];
        for(int i = 0; i < uNumCourses; i++)
                        uCourses[i] = readCourse(in, uInstructors, gStudents, uStudents);

        //Create University object
        university = new University(uName, uTerm, uYear, uStudents, uInstructors, uCourses);
        return university;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
    fe.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

And the code for my EmptyFileException is

```
public class EmptyFileException extends Exception {
String filename;

EmptyFileException() {
}

EmptyFileException(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public String toString() {
    return "The file " + filename + " is empty.";


}
```

}

And the driver is

```
public class TestDriver2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    University ufl = University.readFromFile("university.txt");

            if (ufl != null) {
                System.out.println("\n--Printing out University info--");
                System.out.println(ufl);

                System.out.println("\n--Printing out Students info--");
                Student[] students = ufl.getStudents();
                for (Student s : students)
                        System.out.println("\n" + s);
            }
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. And in case it wasn't clear, the first 2 files compile just fine, only the driver won't compile (which was given to me by my teacher).

**Update**

Added the `throws` clause and it compiled, didn't figure to change the code my teacher gave me.

However now I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at University.readFromFile(University.java:174)
 at TestDriver2.main(TestDriver2.java:8)
```

Comment: So catch it, or declare it to be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws EmptyFileException {
```

(Or insert an appropriate `catch` statement in the code.)

Comment: Thanks! It compiled, didn't figure to change the code my teacher gave me. However (and I have no clue how to format this in comments) now I keep getting this error:Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
        at University.readFromFile(University.java:174)
        at TestDriver2.main(TestDriver2.java:8)

Comment: @user1807895 "now I keep getting this error..." - this is an unrelated problem, post a new question (without code that's not relevant to it) instead of moving the goalposts on this one.

Comment: @user1807895 In said new question include what input it's actually choking at etc.

Comment: @millimoose -- I made the update to the original question (in part just so I could read the traceback).

Comment: @HotLicks This is still something that shouldn't be done. You answered the original question, and should get an accept for that instead of being expected to gradually debug the OP's whole program over SO.

Comment: @millimoose -- Chill.  I wasn't debugging the whole program, just trying to make it possible to read the traceback.